# how do i use WCF service instead of socket client-server application?

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, command

im wondering about how to use WCF service instead of sockets .. to send commands .. someone told me its more powerful than creating a client-server application
my application about

send/receive Commands

chat

file transfer
in my application i have to create at least two sockets on two ports .. one for (chat/commands) and one for fileTransfer ..

```
//this function runs in its own thread
private void Job(object o)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)o;
        NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        try
        {
            string cmd = null;

            while ((cmd = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cmd);
                string[] command = cmd.Split('<');
                switch (command[0])
                {
                    case "root":
                        fmc.root();
                        break;
                    case "explore":
                        fmc.Explore(command[1]);
                        break;
                    case "new_folder":
                        fmc.NewFolder(command[1]);
                        break;
                    case "hidden":
                        fmc.HiddenChecked(command[1]);
                        break;
                    case "delete":
                        fmc.Delete(command[1]);
                        break;
                    case "properties":
                        if (command[1] == "single")
                        {
                            fmc.SingleProperties(command[2]);
                        }
                        else if (command[1] == "multi")
                        {
                            fmc.MultiProperties(command[2]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fmc.DriveProperties(command[2]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "pastefromcopy":
                        fmc.PasteFromCopy(command[1], command[2]);
                        break;
                    //case "confirm":
                     //   break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine(cmd);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { client.Close(); stream.Dispose(); sr.Dispose(); }
    }
```

so do you have any tutorial that would be close to my application.. to execute commands .. or if you can write me a simple client-server WCF .. that solve it the same way . thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are really so many articles out on the web for making a chat service using wcf.  It really depends on the level of what you want to make and how much you would like to learn.
I recommend you to go through a few of these videos [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) first to get the feel for wcf.

Then look through these to find an example of what you would like to create.

- [ASP-Net-chatting-using-WCF-Services-and-JSon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265695/ASP-Net-chatting-using-WCF-Services-and-JSon)
- [Chat-Application-in-ASP-NET-Using-AJAX-Pop-up-Wind](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75135/Chat-Application-in-ASP-NET-Using-AJAX-Pop-up-Wind)
- [WCF-WPF-Chat-Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19752/WCF-WPF-Chat-Application)
- [A-WCF-WPF-Chat-Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25261/A-WCF-WPF-Chat-Application)
- [WCF-Chat-Application.htm](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/componentdevelopment/article.php/c13197__1/WCF-Chat-Application.htm)
- [Microsoft's WCF Chat Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690929%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Have fun creating your service.

Answer (score 0):

The following [link](http://wcfchat.codeplex.com/) would be a good starting point. It details how to write a client server chat application in WCF.